# Editor and HTML/CSS/JS snippet in app

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, editor, android-app, ios-app

1. The HTML/CSS/JS snippet is not currently available in the mobile app.
   Please consider adding that feature to the app.
2. All the indentation of code "disappears", if you try to edit your post in the app.
   Is that something that can be improved upon?
   As this makes simple editing of post that contains indented code impractical, however small the editing you want to make is.

Comment: This should probably be two posts: 1. improve snippet handling in app; and 2. is already here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302501/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I shall edit my post accordingly.

Comment: the original point 2 of this post has been moved to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326455/external-and-internal-css-in-code-snippet

Comment: Can you give an example of what your second point means?  How does indentation disappear?